How can I augment a JSON document when I have an application that is designed to use OpenAI to answer user questions about the document?
I am using an OpenAI API to make a local application that answers questions using a certain document as a main reference. I am using JavaScript where I integrated the OpenAI API, and then CSS and HTML for designing the application.
Now, I am having a hard time augmenting additional instructions to my prompt right before sending it to OpenAI to generate a response (i.e., a Retrieval Augmented Genration or RAG). I started trying to append additional ridiculous instructions like "Start your response with a joke" or "Greet the user first in French" to check whether OpenAI receives the instructions but it doesn't. It just answers the prompt questions and says that it does not know how to refer to any JSON document, despite the document being in the folder that I am working on and augmented into the prompt being sent to OpenAI. Here is my code:
let jsonData = null;

async function loadJsonFile() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('manual.json');
    jsonData = await response.json(); // Store the parsed JSON data
    console.log("Loaded JSON Data:", jsonData); // Log the loaded JSON
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error loading JSON file:", error);
  }
}

async function askQuestion() {
  const question = document.getElementById("question").value;
  const responseElement = document.getElementById("response");

  // Check if jsonData is loaded
  if (!jsonData || Object.keys(jsonData).length === 0) {
    responseElement.innerText =
      "I am unable to access or provide information about the JSON file. Please ensure it is loaded successfully.";
    return;
  }

  // Instructional text to include in the prompt
  const instructionalText = "Start your answer with a joke.";

  // Combine the user's input and instructional text
  const modifiedQuestion = `${question}\n\n${instructionalText}`;

  try {
    // Send the modified question to OpenAI
    const aiResponse = await openAiRequest(modifiedQuestion);

    // Assuming openAiRequest returns the response in a usable format, handle accordingly
    responseElement.innerText = aiResponse || "No response from OpenAI.";
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error while fetching the AI response:", error);
    responseElement.innerText = "Error: Unable to get a response from the AI.";
  }
}

async function openAiRequest(modifiedQuestion) {
  const apiUrl = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions"; // GPT-3.5+ chat endpoint

  // Log the request body to see the exact prompt being sent
  console.log("Request Body:", modifiedQuestion);

  try {
    const jsonContent = JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 2); // Stringify the loaded JSON
    console.log("Trimmed JSON Content (first 500 chars):", jsonContent.slice(0, 500)); // Log part of the JSON content for easier debugging

    const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer [MY-API-KEY]`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        model: "gpt-3.5-turbo", // Or any other model you want to use
        messages: [
          { role: "system", content: "Start your answers with a joke." },
          { role: "user", content: modifiedQuestion },
          { role: "assistant", content: `Use this information from the JSON document as context to answer the user question: ${jsonContent}` }
        ],
        max_tokens: 200,
        temperature: 0.7,
      }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log("OpenAI Response Data:", data); // Log the full OpenAI API response

    if (data && data.choices && data.choices[0] && data.choices[0].message) {
      return data.choices[0].message.content.trim();
    } else {
      console.warn("OpenAI API did not return expected response:", data);
      return "No response received from OpenAI.";
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error with OpenAI API request:", error);
    return "There was an error processing your request. Please try again.";
  }
}

window.onload = loadJsonFile;

I tried augmenting the JSON document, as well as my additional instructions, in the ask Question function and in the OpenAI request function. The Operations Manual Assistant is still seemingly answering like a regular ChatGPT application without the context of the JSON document nor of the additional requests.
